# Arm assembly load string into r0

Tags: assembly, operating-system, raspberry-pi, arm

I am trying to load a string into r0 (for a raspberry pi os). The address of the string is already in r0, and the length is  in r1. I read about the ldr command, however, all of those examples only read the first few characters of the string.
Thanks

Comment: A register can only hold 32 bits (64 bits on 64bit ARMs), which is up to 4 8bit characters. You have to read the string in a loop character-by-character, and do with each character what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from sapanoia - A register can only hold 32 bits (64 bits on 64bit ARMs), which is up to 4 8bit characters. You have to read the string in a loop character-by-character, and do with each character what you want.